# How do I connect a 2016 MacBook Pro to a Display Port monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

Apple's Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter [only works with Thunderbolt displays](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266). So how do I connect my 2016 MacBook Pro to my Display Port monitor?

Comment: Could you use a USB-C to DP adapter? There's also an expensive ($100) Thunderbolt 3 to dual DP adapter.

Comment: Have a look at: [MacBook Pro Thunderbolt 3 adapter guide: How to connect an iPhone, display, hard drive, and more](http://www.macworld.com/article/3136583/macbook-accessories/macbook-pro-thunderbolt-3-adapter-guide-how-to-connect-an-iphone-display-hard-drive-and-more.html#displayport)

Comment: @user3439894 Hmm looks like the listed adapter doesn't support 4K at 60 Hz.